# What is the special syntax for a sub email address in local part of address

Tags: email, rfc5322

I have read somewhere, when searching on how to parse email addresses the best way, that it is possible to have a special string in front or after your local-part of the email address, which is ignored for assigning it to a special mailbox. So something like

mysubgroup#myaddress@example.com would match to the mailbox myaddress@example.com

Does anyone know the correct syntax i've tried #$%&?+^~ as deviding charackter all of them didn't work

Comment: There is no particular standard for this. GMail uses `+`, my ISP's MTA (Exim) uses `-`, other people may use other things. "Mailboxes" are not a concept defined by the RFCs, but are an MUA-specific thing (and the sub-part typically goes after the main address e.g. `john-cv@example.com`).

Comment: Do you know the name for this feature or where dou you found the information for google or exim?

Comment: [Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096?hl=en). Exim I'm sure is configurable.